# Switch statement in PHP

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I am trying to do some error checking.  I want to make it so that if no radio button is checked on an html page, it will pass to the php and tell the user to choose a radio button and a link to go back to that page.

Included is my current code:

PHP

```
<?php


switch($_POST["city"]){
    case "sf":
        echo "Welcome to San Francisco, enjoy the beautiful weather.";
        break;
    case "tokyo":
        echo "Welcome to Tokyo, enjoy the sushi.";
        break;
    case "paris";
        echo "Welcome to Paris, enjoy the Eiffel Tower.";
        break;
    Default:
        echo "Please pick a city.";
        echo "<a href=\"/week7.html\">Go Back</a>";


}

?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="Week7PHP.php" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="city" value="sf">San Francisco<br />
                <input type="radio" name="city" value="paris">Paris<br/>
                <input type="radio" name="city" value="tokyo">Tokyo<br/>
                <input type="submit" id="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is giving an error when it isn't finding any of the radio buttons checked.

This is the error if no option is picked:  Notice: Undefined index: city

Comment: echo $_POST["city"] before switch. Check What it gives.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: city
thats the error

Comment: aside from the semicolon after "paris" syntax-wise there shouldn't be a problem, most likely it's the strictness error level on your php.ini configuration. In any case, please tell us the 'error' message. -EDIT- just saw the Notice: undefined index, I suggest you read up on the php.ini configuration first, for the mean time you can put a '@' on the switch call e.g. switch(@$_POST["city"]) the '@' suppresses error message generation

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  I'll do some reading up on php.ini as well.

Comment: another tip, always check the input submitted from your user e.g. if(isset($_POST["city"])) { ... } a good programming habit to practice :D

Comment: what's with `Default` instead of `default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you may be getting an error is your using `$_POST["city"]` before it was set by posting

I personally would not use a `_POST` `_GET` `_REQUEST` globals within a switch.
I would code a controller no matter how basic the script is that checks and handles these "special" variables.

Something as simple as:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['city'])){
    $city=$_POST['city'];
}else{
    $city='';
}
//Or simpler
$city=(isset($_POST['city']))?$_POST['city']:'';



//The use $city
switch($city){
    case "sf":
        echo "Welcome to San Francisco, enjoy the beautiful weather.";
        break;
    case "tokyo":
        echo "Welcome to Tokyo, enjoy the sushi.";
        break;
    ...
    ...

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the advantage to assigning a second variable if there is no manipulation of the data. There are zero cases where  `switch` inside an `isset()` would be called in appropriately.

Comment: You should also check if submit button is set `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` in that if your PHP should come

Comment: one should always check variables before use, and always check input variables even if my answer hasn't added sanitization it still seems logical

Comment: @Naveen Kumar `submit` button does not have a name attribute so it would not be passed, I know what your saying tho...one should check the whole form.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `break;` after the `default:` option.
And you've got a misplaced semi-colon after "paris" it should be a colon.

```
<?php


switch($_POST["city"]){
    case "sf":
        echo "Welcome to San Francisco, enjoy the beautiful weather.";
        break;
    case "tokyo":
        echo "Welcome to Tokyo, enjoy the sushi.";
        break;
    case "paris":
        echo "Welcome to Paris, enjoy the Eiffel Tower.";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Please pick a city.";
        echo "<a href=\"/week7.html\">Go Back</a>";
        break;

}

?>
```

Comment: You do not need to `break` after the last option, since it's the last option and no further `case` can match.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the switch statement tries to access `$_POST["city"]` in cases where there is none set. This is a perfect use for the [`isset()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if (isset($_POST["city")) {
   /* switch statement */
} else {
   /* form element*/
}
```